# Querydsl ignores common table expression alias for JPA Entities

Tags: java, sql, querydsl

I need to build SQL query with common table expression using QueryDSL:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT BUSINESS_ID FROM BUSINESS WHERE MERCHANT_CODE like ?
)
SELECT t0.*
FROM PAYMENT t0
  LEFT JOIN cte t1 ON t0.PAYER = t1.BUSINESS_ID
  LEFT JOIN cte t2 ON t0.PAYEE = t2.BUSINESS_ID
WHERE (t1.BUSINESS_ID IS NOT NULL OR t2.BUSINESS_ID IS NOT NULL)
```

I have two JPA entities (Payment, Business).

This is how I implemented that:

```java
String merchantCode = "abcd%";
QPayment payment = QPayment.payment;
QBusiness business = QBusiness.business;
QBusiness cte = new QBusiness("cte");
QBusiness merchant1 = new QBusiness("t1");
QBusiness merchant2 = new QBusiness("t2");
Configuration configuration = new Configuration(new OracleTemplates());

new JPASQLQuery<>(entityManager, configuration)
  .with(cte,
      JPAExpressions.selectDistinct(business.businessId).from(business)
      .where(business.merchantCode.like(merchantCode)))
  .select(payment)
  .from(payment)
    .leftJoin(cte, merchant1).on(payment.payer.eq(merchant1.businessId))
    .leftJoin(cte, merchant2).on(payment.payee.eq(merchant2.businessId))
  .where(merchant1.businessId.isNotNull()
      .or(merchant2.businessId.isNotNull()));
```

And the problem is that during `leftJoin` it doesn't treat `cte` as a link, instead it inserts table name and two aliases: `LEFT JOIN BUSINESS cte t1 ON ...`. I tried different templates – didn't help.

Am I doing something wrong or it's a QueryDSL bug?

Answer (score 0):

Take a good look at [the tutorial](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.2.2/reference/html/ch02.html)

```
QCat cat = QCat.cat;
QCat mate = new QCat("mate");
QCat kitten = new QCat("kitten");
query.from(cat)
    .innerJoin(cat.mate, mate)
    .leftJoin(cat.kittens, kitten)
    .list(cat);
```

You will want to `.leftjoin(cte.merchant1, merchant1).on(...)` or whatever the corresponding field is called in the parent "cte". 
Basically you need to name the field which you want to join. Just stating the meta model does not suffice as there is no way of telling what you actually want. You can see it in your code (as well in the tutorial's kitten example): you have two *Merchant* you want to join to the *cte*, so which one is which.

The `.on()`-clause just states the conditions under which a join is valid, like you could place filters there.

.

Comment: I thought that join restriction is applied only to JPQL, unlike `SQLQuery`, where I can `join(entity, alias).on(join_condition)` [see "Alternatively the join condition..."](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.1.4/reference/html/ch02s03.html#d0e1200). Alias is used to differentiate between two instances of one CTE that being joined. Since `JPASQLQuery` is based on `AbstractSQLQuery` I believe I can use that join-method.

Comment: Ah I see. Maybe that method depends on a 'proper' meta model. I highly recommend to Auto-Create your meta models (Maven, Gradle), first you can skip the `new QMyEntity("name")` part, plus you can be sure the model is actually correct. Anyways, the Cat-Example should work, even if there are no relations between the tables in the first place. Did this lots of times

Answer (score 0):

JPQL doen't support CTEs, as we can see in [grammar](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html). And querydsl works over JPQL. CTEs are pretty vendor-specific, so you'll have to do one of following:

1. Rewrite query to be JPA-compatible
2. Use JPA native query
3. Query sql with querydsl (actually I don't remember if it supports CTEs)

From all above I would chose the 2nd option. Making native queries doen't harm your code. It makes your code more performant.

Comment: Are you sure you not confusing `JPAQuery` and `JPASQLQuery`. With 1st one there is no chance to create an CTE, but 2nd one extends `AbstractSQLQuery` and it has `with()` method.
I wish I could use native, but I also need to add 0-4 dynamic conditions. A friend of mine suggested to use JDBC template. So far I'm going to follow that path.

Comment: @ShamilAbsalikov sorry, I'm really confusing them

Comment: @ShamilAbsalikov but I still think that native will be better. Jdbc template, jooq - anything will work.
I'll tell you more: nobody can prohibit you to build query string with ifs and then bind parameters with these ifs too